# Print HTTP request in Python Django

Tags: python, django

I want to print the entire request object that comes to the server. I need to see all of the parameters that the request carries from the client since I don't have the clients's code (it's an Android client). I'm in the view.py file, and I'm using the function

```
def index(request):

    return HttpResponse("test params")
```

to print the request object

Please suggest code. It would be even better if I can print the request in the browser and not in the console.

Comment: `print request` is for console.

Comment: `return HttpResponse(request)` ?

Comment: return HttpResponse(request) is not working I get a empty webpage

Comment: Try render(request, 'mypage.html', {'request': request}).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Django Debug Toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar) which allows you to view a lot of debugging information including request and session.

From its documentation:

> Currently, the following panels have been written and are working:
>
> - Django version
> - Request timer
> - A list of settings in settings.py
> - Common HTTP headers
> - GET/POST/cookie/session variable display
> - Templates and context used, and their template paths
> - SQL queries including time to execute and links to EXPLAIN each query
> - List of signals, their args and receivers
> - Logging output via Python's built-in logging, or via the logbook    module

Answer (score 10):

```
import sys

def req(request)
   print(request.__dict__, file=sys.stderr)
```

Comment: Faster/easier than the accepted answer

Answer (score 6):

```
from django.utils.html import escape
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse(escape(repr(request)))
```

Comment: This just returns `&lt;WSGIRequest: GET &#x27;/path/to/endpoint/&#x27;&gt;` now